# Reference lost on forwarding (and no auto-conversion to save me) - why?

Tags: templates, c++11, factory, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I'm writing a Factory for producing instances of subclasses of a base class using their name, and using this (templated) factory with my class `Foo`. Never mind the entire code, but essentially, the factory has a map from string to functions creating instances; and a template parameter controls which arguments these functions take. In my case, the ctor of `Foo`, and any subclass of foo, takes a `const Bar&`, and that's what the variadic template for ctor arguments consist of.

I have:

```
template<typename SubclassKey, typename T, typename... ConstructionArgs>
class Factory {
public:
    using Instantiator = T* (*)(ConstructionArgs&&...);
private:
    template<typename U>
    static T* createInstance(ConstructionArgs&&... args)
    {
        return new U(std::forward<ConstructionArgs>(args)...);
    }
    using Instantiators = std::unordered_map<SubclassKey,Instantiator>;
    Instantiators subclassInstantiators;

public:
    template<typename U>
    void registerSubclass(const SubclassKey&  subclass_id)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<T, U>::value,
            "This factory cannot register a class which is is not actually "
            "derived from the factory's associated class");
        auto it = subclassInstantiators.find(subclass_id);

       if (it != subclassInstantiators.end()) {
            throw std::logic_error("Repeat registration of the same subclass in this factory.");
        }
        subclassInstantiators.emplace(subclass_id, &createInstance<U>);
    }
};
```

And by popular demand, here's also...

```
class Foo {
    using FooFactory = Factory<std::string, Foo, const Bar&>;
private:
    static FooFactory& getTestFactory() {
        static FooFactory kernel_test_factory;
        return kernel_test_factory;
    }
    //...
public:
    //...
    template <typename U>
    static void registerInFactory(const std::string& name_of_u) {
        Foo::getTestFactory().registerSubclass<U>(name_of_u);
    }
    Bar bar;
    Foo(const Bar& bar_) : bar(bar_) { };
    virtual ~Foo() {}
    // ...
};

class NiceFoo : public Foo {
    // no ctors and dtors
};
```

Unfortunately, for some reason, when I call

I get a complaint about the ctor expecting a `const Bar&` while the argument list I supposedly provide in my `createInstance` is actually a `const Bar`.

Questions:

- Why is the reference "disappearing"?
- Am I doing something wrong? Should I be approaching this matter differently?

GCC error output:

```
/home/joeuser/myproj/../util/Factory.h(36): error: no instance of constructor "NiceFoo::NiceFoo" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (const Bar)
          detected during:
            instantiation of "T *util::Factory<SubclassKey, T, ConstructionArgs...>::createInstance<U>(ConstructionArgs &&...) [with SubclassKey=std::string, T=Foo, ConstructionArgs=<const Bar &>, U=NiceFoo]" 
(59): here
            instantiation of "void util::Factory<SubclassKey, T, ConstructionArgs...>::registerSubclass<U>(const SubclassKey &) [with SubclassKey=std::string, T=Foo, ConstructionArgs=<const Bar &>, U=NiceFoo]" 
/home/joeuser/myproj/../Foo.h(79): here
            instantiation of "void Foo::registerInFactory<U>(const std::string &) [with U=NiceFoo]" 
/home/joeuser/myproj/NiceFoo.cpp(122): here
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Is `createInstance` a class member? A class template member? Are `ConstructionArgs` class template template parameters? Function template template parameters? What does `NiceFoo` expect? Etc.

Comment: @Angew: The thing is, a complete example won't be very minimal. But I will put up the whole Factory class. To answer your questions, `ConstructionArgs` is a variadic template parameter, and the `NiceFoo` ctor expects a `const Bar&` like all `Foo`s

Comment: Does the compiler also report anything like "potentially applicable overloads" of `NiceFoo::NiceFoo`?

Comment: And BTW, all that is missing from an MCVE now is a (trivial) definition of `Foo`, `NiceFoo`, and a call site. Not *that* much code. (I'm assuming that you've left out a `template <class U>` at a few places, too).

Comment: @einpoklum it doesn't need to mirror your code, it just needs to compile

Comment: You need a `using Foo::Foo;` in your `NiceFoo`.

Comment: @T.C.: Looks like that did the trick. A lot of code for a short oversight. Thanks. It's covered by Angew's answer though.

Comment: @einpoklum This shows why posting an MCVE is important: sometimes, the error is not where one would expect it.

Comment: @Angew: Right you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your code: the immediate one, and a fundamental one.

The immediate one is that `NiceFoo` does not declare any constructors. You claimed that "it inherits `Foo`'s constructors," but that's not the case in the code you've shown. Inheriting constructors would be achieved by this:

```
class NiceFoo : public Foo {
public:
  using Foo::Foo;
}
```

Without the `using` declaration, you just have a class with no constructors declared (it will have the copy, move, and parameterless ones generated by default, but no new ones).

---

There is also a fundamental issue in your design: You're trying to use template parameters of a class template in perfect forwarding. That doesn't work; perfect forwarding relies on template argument deduction, which only happens with function templates.

In other words, this: `ConstructionArgs&&...` does not create forwarding references, but plain old rvalue references. In the concrete case you've presented, it does not really matter, because `ConstructionArgs` is `const Bar &` and reference collapsing makes it work out. But if you had included a value type (and not reference type) among the constructor arguments, `createInstance` would have been using plain rvalue references and initialisation from an lvalue would have been impossible.

The correct solution to this would be to have `ConstructionArgs` mirror *exactly* what the constructor of `T` expects—in other words, drop the `&&` from use of `ConstructionArgs` everywhere<s>, and use `std::move` instead of `std::forward` inside `createInstance`</s>. One second thought, the `std::forward` should be able to stay and do the right thing; basically equivalent to a no-op for lvalue references, and to a `std::move` for values and rvalue references.

Comment: But won't an `std::move()` try to, well, move stuff out of what I've passed? And why would `std::move()` work on anything that's const?

Comment: @einpoklum I've just addressed that bit. But the only thing where this matters would be a non-`const` lvalue reference. For values, `std::forward` and `std::move` are the same. For `const Xyz&`, `std::move` results in a `const Xyz&&`, which cannot bind to normal move operations, but does bind to `const Xyz&`, resulting in the right thing again.

Comment: Also... should I drop the && everywhere, or just in some places?

Comment: @einpoklum It is used in two places in the code you've shown, and in both of them it should be removed.